plugin development code standard not matching for SQL query
In WordPress before submitting plugin need to check code with the PCP
It keeps showing warning of Use of a direct database call is discouraged
I tried to follow all the coding standard given by WordPress and also tried to solve the error from previous question and other suggestions.
Things i have tried already is adding this comment after my code /* db call ok; no cache ok */ still it showing warning on this line of my code $scripts = $wpdb->get_results
This is my code
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
$current_post_type = get_post_type();
$current_post_id = get_the_ID();

$script_column = 'header_script';

$cache_key = 'my_custom_scripts_cache_' . $current_post_type;
$scripts = wp_cache_get($cache_key);
if ($scripts === false) {
    $scripts = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT %i, postsid_to_exclude, inclscripttag_header, inclscripttag_footer FROM %i WHERE FIND_IN_SET(%s, target_post_types) AND status = %d",
            $script_column,
            $table_name,
            $current_post_type,
            1
        )
    ); /* db call ok; no cache ok */
    wp_cache_set($cache_key, $scripts);
}

Also i have checked this solution suggested here , but using this can reject my plugin from WordPress? or it is safe to use? is there any other solution for this?

Try establishing the $wpdb->prepare() first, then the $wpdb->get_results() - I don't know if that'll make a difference but I have never seen the prepare inside of the get_results.

Tried that but showing same notice.

To be honest, I'm not sure if you can trust this plugin 100%.
I run the test on my plugin, that is already in repo, and it showed me few false alarms. I put your code inside my plugin code and run the test again and... it didn't show me the error you have.
Also, my Code Sniffer in Visual Studio code shows different errors that are not reported by the plugin:

You do not need to use double quote
You are not using Yoda condition
%i is available only for WordPress 6.2 and above, so it is safer to use %s
= are not aligned

Code after changes:
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name        = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
    $current_post_type = get_post_type();
    $current_post_id   = get_the_ID(); // this one is unused

    $script_column = 'header_script';

    $cache_key = 'my_custom_scripts_cache_' . $current_post_type;
    $scripts   = wp_cache_get( $cache_key );

    if ( false === $scripts ) {
        $scripts = $wpdb->get_results(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                'SELECT %s, postsid_to_exclude, inclscripttag_header, inclscripttag_footer FROM %s WHERE FIND_IN_SET(%s, target_post_types) AND status = %d',
                $script_column,
                $table_name,
                $current_post_type,
                1
            )
        ); /* db call ok; no cache ok */
        wp_cache_set( $cache_key, $scripts );
    }

(I recommend to use Code Sniffer inside your IDE, will save you time.
I'm using this one:
https://github.com/wongjn/vscode-php-sniffer
And you need to use it with WordPress Coding Standards (WPCS):
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards?tab=readme-ov-file
